# Problem in downloading new profile in Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

I have problem in downloading new profiles in Kdenlive.
In all cases (Wipes, render profile, project profile, title), nothing is being downloaded and I only see 'loading data' as you see in the screenshot.

[image: Problem in downloading new stuff into Kdenlive]

What is the problem and what is the solution for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They moved the website in 2013 and left the profiles behind:

http://www.kdenlive.org/mantis/view.php?id=3133